# sound notifiction after insert new row in datatables (ticketing system)

Tags: php, jquery, plugins, datatables

> i have real time table like a ticketing system.
>   i want if received a new request(insert a new row to database table ) in every 3 seconds play for me a sound notification.each request showed in datatables jquery plugin(json api).plz help me.

```
 var table = $('#example').DataTable({

    "sAjaxSource": "check-request.php",

    "aoColumns": [
        {'mData': 'email'},
        {'mData': 'mob'},
        {'mData': 'date'},

        {
            'mData': 'requestid',
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData) {
                $(nTd).html("<a href='localhost?id=" + oData.requestid + "'>answer</a>");
            }
        },
        {
            'mData': 'status',
            render: function (data) {
                switch (data) {
                    case '0' :
                        return '<i class="fa fa-unchecked></i>';
                        break;
                    case '1' :
                        return '<i class="fa fa-check"></i>';
                        break;
                    default  :
                        return 'N/A';
                }
            }
        }
                    ]
});


table
    .order([2, 'desc'])
    .draw();

setInterval(function () {
    table.ajax.reload(null, false);

}, 3000);
```